# Recurrence Relation: Solving BigO of T(n-1)

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence

I'm solving some recurrence relation problems for Big O.

```
T(n) = T(n-1)
```

I started with:

```
T(n)   = T(n-1)
T(n-1) = T(n-2)
..
T(n) = T(n-k)
```

Now setting k to n-1

```
T(n) = T(1)
```

So the result is

```
T(n) = O(1)
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but I'm uncertain that this is so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a base case, yes, that's correct.

I'm assuming the recurrence is defined as

> T(0) = k (for some constant k), and
>
> T(n+1) = T(n)

Then you can prove by induction that T(n) = k for all natural numbers n.

- **Base case**: If n = 0, then T(n) = T(0) = k, as required.
- **Inductive step:** Assume T(n) = k.  Then T(n + 1) = T(n) = k, as required.

Therefore, T(n) = k = O(1).

Hope this helps!